# mysql myISAM, альтернатива транзакциям

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно обеспечить сохранение целостности данных при записи в БД mySql, таблицы myISAM, ведь механизм транзакций отсутствует.
Нагрузка на запись будет небольшая. Но структура данных сложная и во многих случаях будет необходима запись в несколько таблиц сразу при одном сохранении данных. И хотелось бы для этих случаев реализовать механизм, позволяющий имитировать наличие транзакций - т.е. чтобы либо всё записалось, либо ничего, в случае ошибки на любом из шагов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь об атомарности — или ставить блокировки в начале транзакции и не снимать их до окончания (приемлемо только если транзакции короткие, а одновременно работает максимум один клиент), или строить свои журналы.

С самодельными журналами — когда начинается псевдо-транзакция, на каждый запрос работаем с таблицей-журналом. Например, когда сделали выборку — записали что выбрали (чтобы была изоляция хотя бы на уровне repeatable reads). Сделали UPDATE — на самом деле его не делали, а записали в журнал «при коммите вот это надо обновить с вот такого на вот такое.» И т.д., причем важно, чтобы в обход этой самодельной системы никто не работал. Когда проходит коммит — лепим блокировку на все ряды и выполняем записанное в журнале, потом снимаем блокировку и удаляем выполненные записи.

Чем все это городить, проще и дешевле настроить InnoDB, даже если дело пахнет сменой сервера. Потому что разработка своей системы транзакций (с учетом рисков потерять данные из-за ошибок реализации) стоит явно дороже.

Если речь о надежности — тут вообще никак.

По одной простой причине — даже если сделать самодельные журналы в виде таблиц, то все равно, насколько я в курсе, нет никакого способа затребовать у MySQL, чтобы та действительно гарантированно записала-«сбросила» данные на диск. А это значит, что на любой чих БД может побиться, когда и данные и журнал будут «сломаны», и привести БД в целостное состояние будет проблематично.

Comment: Спасибо, я бы перевела БД на InnoDB, но боюсь снижения производительности при чтении, нагрузка у нас предполагается порядка 100 000 посетителей в день и вся она - только на чтение. Т.е. заполнять данные в админке будет один человек всего. Вот и получается, что, вроде, и не целесообразно переводить. Рассматривала вариант совместного использования в БД таблиц двух типов,чтобы на InnoDB перевести лишь ту небольшую часть таблиц, где необходимо использовать транзакции, но тоже часто встречается информация о том, что это грозит различными проблемами в плане недостаточности ресурсов сервера.

Comment: @Mariya, если будут проблемы с производительностью чтения — лучше поставьте кэш типа memcached или Redis. Или просто в файловой системе можно данные кэшировать. При обновлении данных в БД кэшированную копию старых данных, разумеется, стирать.

Answer (score 0):

Понимаю, мой комментарий устарел, но возможно кому-то будет интересно.

В случае, когда основная нагрузка идет на группу таблиц где у нас один писатель и много читателей можно имитировать псевдо-транзакционное поведение с помощью снимков LVM.

Подробнее механизм описан здесь:

http://wiki.opennet.ru/MySQL_LVM_Update